# In Outlook, how can I switch view from a task pane add-in to a module extension?

Tags: javascript, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We're working with task pane add-ins and module extension add-ins in Outlook.

We need to be able to display a button in a task pane, that changes Outlook's view to a page in our module extension when clicked, passing information from the task pane's context to it.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible, but very interesting and useful case. In manifest those are two different extension points which user invoke from different Outlook UI parts. It's probably challenging to open module extension and close corresponding task pane and vise-versa. Well, I would be interested myself to hear the answer from Microsoft team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An API to open a module extension point from a task pane isn't available today. You can submit a request for this API on the Outlook add-ins [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778).

Please note that the module extension point is exclusive to Outlook on Windows, while the task pane extension point is available on other platforms (so Outlook users on other platforms wouldn't be able to open the module extension).

It will depend on your scenario, though one alternative to consider may be to show a dialog with the [displayDialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). The task pane would continue to run behind the dialog, but the add-in could close the task pane when the dialog is closed.